# Proving $\frac{1}{ x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

I am trying to prove the function in the title is not uniformly continuous on (0,2].
 Different from the proof given in [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647764/proving-1-over-x2-is-not-uniformly-continuous), I proceed to show the proof following [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-UmtZkCHwU) as follows:
\begin{equation}
|1/x^2 - 1/y^2|=\frac{|y-x||y+x|}{x^2y^2}
\end{equation}
 (after simplification).
 Since both $x,y \in (0,2]$  above eq. reduces to \begin{equation}
|1/x^2 - 1/y^2|= \frac{|y-x|}{4}<\frac{\delta}{4} (\text{by the definition of continuity}).
\end{equation}
Now if I pick $\delta=4\varepsilon$, I don't arrive at the contradiction. Any hint where I am wrong will help.

Comment: How did you get $|x^{-2}-y^{-2}|<|y-x|/4$? Somehow I doubt this is true.

Comment: max value of $|x+y|$ could be 4 since both $x, y \in (0,2]$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: But denominator $x^{-2} y^{-2}$ may be arbitrarily large.

Comment: How come? if Both $x$ and $y$ are bounded.

Comment: They may be as close to zero as you want. In the denominator it is always the inverse inequality-the smaller the denominator is, the bigger the fraction is.

Comment: Oh. I got it now. I was looking at the numerator and denominator separately. In fact, I can make rhs of the 1st eq. to go to infinity by choosing x and y really small and no $\epsilon$ can bound that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta>0$, choose $x\in (0,2]$ such that $x<\frac{\delta}2$ and choose $y=\frac{x}2$. Then
$$
|y-x| = \frac x2 < \frac \delta{2}<\delta
$$
and since $x\leq 2$
$$
\left|\frac1 {x^2}-\frac 1{y^2}\right| = \left|\frac1 {x^2}-\frac 4{x^2}\right|=\frac{3}{x^2} \geq \frac 34.
$$
This contradicts the definition of uniform continuity on $(0,2]$.

---

If you are allowed to use some results on uniformly continuous functions there are several faster ways to solve the exercise. For instance, the extension theorem states that if $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous then it is possible to extend $f$ to the closure of $A$ in such a way that the extension is uniformly continuous (and, in particular, continuous). Since there is no way to extend $f(x)=\frac 1{x^2}$ to $[0,2]$ to a continuous function, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,2]$.